# $form_FieldName$ empty value issue Sitecore EXM

Tags: sitecore-forms, exm

I have a scenario, where we have 3 fields(optional - Single line Field)
Preferred location 1, Location 2, Location 3
When user fill form based on the field value sending email to the user.

If user filled 1,2 and 3 fields then no issue in the email working fine.
But if user filled only 1 and 2 (or any 2 fields between them), then send email Failed.

Noticed it is because $form_Location3$ value is empty.

Any suggestion/feedback that why $form_Location3$ with empty value giving error as 'System.NullReferenceException',?

Comment: did you try passing defaults values in the single-line text fields?

Comment: @RamanGupta by passing default value it works. But if there is no value for field then exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is Sitecore known issue
and found fix for this https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.79007